# How can i solve my java netbean coding error?

Tags: java, mysql, error-handling, netbeans-8

In this below code, when i run this it always working 'catch' method, but I putting data in mySql successfully.
It always showing the result "Student Id already exist", that meant of it is working only catch method, not 'try' method..
Hera anyone can solve my solve my problem ?

```
try
        {
            Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate("insert into student values('"+studentID+"','"+name+"','"+fatherName+"','"+section+"','"+section+"','"+batch+"','"+department+"','"+courseName+"')");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Updated");
            setVisible(false);
            new newStudent().setVisible(true);
        }
catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Id already exist");
            setVisible(false);
            new newStudent().setVisible(true);
        }
```

Comment: What information is contained in the exception `e`? That'll tell you what the error is.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the catch phrase and debug/examine what kind of Exception you're getting. That may give you (and us) more of an idea what the root of the problem is.

Comment: Since your catch block can catch any type of exception, not just a SQL exception, and you have other statements within the try-block, I'd wager a guess that it isn't actually the database interaction. It's probably something about showing the dialog

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, I see the below line of your code is a kind of logical errors:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Student Id already exist");
```

the above line is wrong because writing such a line imposes a wrong assumption which is that every error occurs while insertion means it's due to a duplicate ID, but this is not always the case, errors may occur for other reasons, so add the below line inside the catch block to print the exception to see what is really happened, after that you can fix the problem.

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: it always showing only 'catch' case

Comment: @Md. Rase add `e.printStackTrace();` to the catch block, run the program then copy the console output after the error occured then paste the output here.